# Finding space between 2 symbols without considering space between second set of 2 symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

```
|this is a string| |this is another string|    | |
```

I am trying to find a method to just alert when a user has entered two symbols without any letters inside. I'm currently using regex, but it is catching the space between the first and second set of strings.

Comment: Could you give an example of something that should and something that should not match anything? It is not clear what you are searching for. Perhaps some context on why you want to find this and why the input looks the way it does would help as clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can account for any amount/kind of whitespace between two characters with `\s*`.  So, to find two `|` characters with nothing but whitespace between them, you could search for `\|\s*\|`.  (The `|` needs to be escaped because it has special meaning to regex as an `or` operator, for example, `dog|cat` matches either `dog` or `cat.)

Comment: That's what I have now, but it catches the ending ```|``` of the first word, and the beginning ```|``` of the second word. I only want to find a set of  ```| |``` without anything inside of it.

So ```|the following space should not be caught|``` ```|only the next set|``` shouldn't catch anything, only a ```| |``` without anything in between them

Comment: I'm confused. Perhaps a more clear example of what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function hasTwoConsecutiveSymbols (str, symb = '|') {
  return str.replace(/\s/g, '').includes(`${symb}${symb}`)
}

console.log(hasTwoConsecutiveSymbols('|this is a string| |this is another string| | |')) //true

// so you could do alert thus:
if (hasTwoConsecutiveSymbols('|this is a string| |this is another string| | |')) alert("No words between pipes")
```

And you could change what symbol is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really program javascript, but this seemed fun as it was more of a regex question, so I tried it using an online javascript regex simulator. Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
"(\|\s*\|)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(\|\s*\|)"
```

might work? it matches a | character with any amount of optional whitespace in the middle, followed by another | character which is either not preceded or not followed by a word character. Hope it helps!

[link to regex to test](https://regex101.com/r/7tUs33/1)

Update:

try

```
(\|\s*\|)[^\w]|[^\w](\|\s*\|)
```

instead. I cut out the look aheads and behinds, but it should still work. Anyone who actually knows anything about javascript feel free to let me know if this answer fails for some reason again!

Comment: Unfortunatly, javascript doesn't support lookbehind!

Comment: That's unfortunate... Do lookaheads still work? I wonder why the tester actually worked. I guess I can try going back to the drawing board.

Comment: Lookaheads are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\B\|\s\|\B` (matches any `|<white-space>|` not bounded by words.

https://regex101.com/r/T39uFS/1

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thanks!